# Protocol for automatic (and possibly fast) user type conversions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion

Assume I have performance-oriented type `mylib.color.Hardware`, and its user-friendly counterparts `mylib.color.RGB` and `mylib.color.HSB`. When user-friendly color passed into library functions, it gets converted into `color.Hardware`. Now it is implemented by examining type of passed arg. But in future I want to accept and auto-convert from any type, which provides corresponding conversion feature. For example, third-party library that implements 'otherlib.color.LAB'.

Right now I am playing with prototype, something like this:

```
class somelib:
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self, value):
            assert isinstance(value, int)
            self._value = value
        def get(self):
            return self._value

class userlib:
    class B(object):
        def __init__(self, value):
            self._value = value
        def __toA(self):
            try: value = int(self._value)
            except: value = 0
            return somelib.A(value)
        __typecasts__ = {somelib.A: __toA}

def autocast(obj, cast_type):
    if isinstance(obj, cast_type): return obj
    try: casts = getattr(obj, '__typecasts__')
    except AttributeError: raise TypeError, 'type cast protocol not implemented at all in', obj
    try: fn = casts[cast_type]
    except KeyError: raise TypeError, 'type cast to {0} not implemented in {1}'.format(cast_type, obj)
    return fn(obj)

def printValueOfA(a):
    a = autocast(a, somelib.A)
    print 'value of a is', a.get()

printValueOfA(userlib.B(42.42)) # value of a is 42
printValueOfA(userlib.B('derp')) # value of a is 0
```

And here is my second prototype, less intrusive but more verbose:

```
# typecast.py

_casts = dict()

def registerTypeCast(from_type, to_type, cast_fn = None):
    if cast_fn is None:
        cast_fn = to_type
    key = (from_type, to_type)
    global _casts
    _casts[key] = cast_fn

def typeCast(obj, to_type):
    if isinstance(obj, to_type): return obj
    from_type = type(obj)
    key = (from_type, to_type)
    fn = _casts.get(key)
    if (fn is None) or (fn is NotImplemented):
        raise TypeError, "type cast from {0} to {1} not provided".format(from_type, to_type)
    return fn(obj)

# test.py
from typecast import *
registerTypeCast(int, str)
v = typeCast(42, str)
print "result:", type(v), repr(v)
```

**Questions.** Is there exists library with same functional? (I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but my google-fu yields None.) Or may be You can suggest better (perhaps more pythonic) approach?

EDIT: Added 2nd prototype.

Comment: If you are willing to add a `__typecasts__` attribute to each class, why not add a method like `hardware_color` that returns a `color.Hardware` object?

Comment: @JanneKarila Because exact type of `color.Hardware` will be known "at runtime". I have two back-ends. When `mylib` initializes, it binds some own symbols to corresponding symbols in currently selected backend.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a component architecture and adaptation. The [Zope Component Architecture](http://www.muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html) lets you register interfaces and adapters; a central registry to look up converters from one type to another. As long as an adapter exists to convert a value to the target type, you can pass any object into your API.

You start by defining what interface the target type requires:

```
from zope.interface import Interface, Attribute

class IHardware(Interface):
    """A hardware colour"""

    bar = Attribute("The bar value for the frobnar")

    def foo():
        """Foo the bar for spam and eggs"""
```

Any class can then *implement* that interface (instances of such a class would *provide* the interface).

```
from zope.interface import implements

class Hardware(object):
    implements(IHardware)

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def foo(self):
        return self.bar + ' and spam and eggs'
```

For your RGB class, you then register an adapter; it helps if you have an `IRGB` interface, but it is not required:

```
 from zope.interface import implements
 from zope.component import adapts
 from zope.component import getGlobalSiteManager


 class RGB(object):
     def __init__(self, r, g, b):
         self.r, self.g, self.b = r, g, b


class RGBtoHardwareAdapter(object):
    implements(IHardware)
    adapts(RGB)

    def __init__(self, rgb_instance):
        self._rgb = rgb_instance
        self.bar = '{},{},{}'.format(rgb_instance.r, rgb_instance.g, rgb_instance.b)

    def foo(self):
        return self.bar + ' in rgb and spam and eggs'


 gsm = getGlobalSiteManager()
 gsm.registerAdapter(RGBtoHardwareAdapter)
```

Now your API just needs to 'cast' your values to `IHardware`:

```
def some_api_call(hardware):
    hardware = IHardware(hardware)
```

That's it. If the `hardware` value *directly* provides the `IHardware` interface, it is returned unchanged. If it is a `RGB` instance, an adapter is found in the registry; the adapter is created (`RGBtoHardwareAdapter(hardware)` is called) and will act *just like* a `IHardware` object.

You can also have your adapter return an actual `Hardware()` object; the above example returns a proxy object instead, but the principle is the same.

Python's [Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) approach interfaces from a different direction, namely ducktyping. You can test if a given object conforms to the ABCs methods and attributes. It does not offer adaptation however.

Comment: Oh my godness, this is huge. Component architecture is overkill for me. And I guess it will be slow, but I need thousands of casts per second. Also I have second prototype (just added it to my post) where I am registering cast functions, but it is way more lightweight. Anyways, thank you for answer, interesting read.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain: It is pretty optimized, actually. Whole high-traffic web sites rely on it being fast. But a mapping from type to conversion function / method is fine too.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain: FWIW, the `__adapts__` method is included in the [C optimizations for `zope.interface`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.interface/blob/master/src/zope/interface/_zope_interface_coptimizations.c); it may be a bit more formal than what you were looking for but it is not slow. :-)

Comment: Oh, how could I forget that python modules may be written in C. ^_^